# Windows WINAPI SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES functionality inside Terminal Services Server session

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, terminal-services

The following code works for a normal desktop setup:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES 0x0069
#define SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES 0x0068

/*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx
BOOL WINAPI SystemParametersInfo(
  _In_     UINT uiAction,
  _In_     UINT uiParam,
  _Inout_  PVOID pvParam,
  _In_     UINT fWinIni
);
*/
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc>1){
        int numLines = _ttoi(argv[1]);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES, numLines, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But apparently SystemParametersInfo is systemwide. Is there any way to this only in the current user session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to modify the scroll wheel setting per user session.

If your app is too-sensitive or not-sensitive enough to the scroll wheel, you'll have to add a setting to the app for scaling the input.